# He had made justice finer

Tags: riddle

> Given a name that fit his character
>   It was he who had made justice finer
>   Posed to be at the top, that none stood higher
>   Presently he remains one man, that many admire

Not sure if it's good :-)

Comment: This could be any superhero? :D

Comment: Wow. Another riddle about Erdoğan. Sheesh.

Comment: As it is, this is much too broad. Can you add more stanzas that point to specific details?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is:

> Superman

Given a name that fit his character

> He is a *super*hero

It was he who had made justice finer

> He fights crime and is part of the Justice League.

Posed to be at the top, that none stood higher

> Super means above; over or beyond in Latin.

Presently he remains one man, that many admire

> "Many admire" speaks for itself, "one man" means there aren´t any super*men*? Please note: I am not superfamiliar (pun intended) with DC-comics.